# How to get transaction line records from NetSuite using NETSUITE SDK?

Tags: rest, etl, netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve NetSuite Transaction Line IDs using either REST API or Netsuite SDK. The netsuite object type does not include Transaction Line.

I am referring this link for NetSuite SDK: https://github.com/fylein/netsuite-sdk-py

Any help on this?

Thanks

I am referring this link for NetSuite SDK: https://github.com/fylein/netsuite-sdk-py